Trying to Dockerize Maven Application but got "release version 21 not supported"
New to Java and Docker, trying to dockerize this (my first Spring Boot application) with:
Dockerfile


FROM maven:3.8.4-jdk-11 AS build

COPY src /app/src
COPY pom.xml /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN mvn clean install -U

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/target/mal-randomizer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Got this error multiple times last night:
20.09 [INFO] Compiling 8 source files with javac [debug release 21] to target/classes
20.18 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20.18 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
20.18 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20.18 [INFO] Total time:  19.160 s
20.18 [INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-22T14:49:00Z
20.18 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20.18 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project mal-randomizer: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported -> [Help 1]
20.18 [ERROR] 
20.18 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
20.18 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
20.18 [ERROR] 
20.18 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
20.18 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I tried multiple solutions such as:

redefining my JAVA_HOME env
changed the image
changed pom.xml Java version, maven-compiler target and source*

*If I downgrade the Java version too much (below Java 16), my code won't run since records have been introduced in 16.
I believe the solution lies in the pom.xml still:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.victorfernandesneto</groupId>
    <artifactId>mal-randomizer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mal-randomizer</name>
    <description>MyAnimeList&apos;s Unofficial List Randomizer</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Your build is a mess. You are running maven with Java 11, try to run the application with Java 8, while your application requires java 21.  Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17 or higher, anything lower it will not run on. So use proper java versions for the images used in your build. The solution isn't in your pom.xml but in your dockerfile. Also what is it you want to dockerize, the build or just the application? If it is the latter, ditch your Dockerfile and just run mvnw spring-boot:build-image to get a containerized application.

Two things are not really matching: maven:3.8.4-jdk-11 in your dockerfile and <java.version>21</java.version> in your pom.xml. That means you are trying to build the application with Java 21, but you are using a maven image that supports Java up to version 11, which will not work.
That's proof by the error message
error: release version 21 not supported … (by an image with JDK 11).
In addition, the image you are using to run the built application obviously uses an even lower Java version: openjdk:8-jre-alpine.
That will not work either… You're going get a similar error message as soon as the build is done with the correct Java version.
The Java version from the pom.xml must be supported by the build image and by the image that later runs the application, so use a maven:3.8.4-jdk-21 (or a different maven version) for the build and an openjdk:21-jre-alpine for the run.

I see... I didn't find any Maven jdk-21 images in Docker Hub. But I did find for Java 17, so I changed the images to maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17, openjdk:17-jdk-oracle and changed pom.xml version to <java.version>17</java.version>. Got the build running! Thank you, so I need to be a bit more careful while building so I won't be running into these errors again.

I'm glad I could help… I think such a version mismatch is a mistake one just has to make at least once in order to keep the versions in mind, forever!

I tried the maven eclipse temurin-21 image for JDK-21 maven:3.9.8-eclipse-temurin-21 for building the service and openjdk:21 for building my docker image. This worked for me for Java version 21.
Updated code of your DockerFile
FROM maven:3.9.8-eclipse-temurin-21 AS build

COPY src /app/src

COPY pom.xml /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN mvn clean install -U

FROM openjdk:21
COPY --from=build /app/target/mal-randomizer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Make sure the version in pom.xml is Java version 21 if you are using the above mentioned DockerFile.
pom.xml
...
<java.version>21</java.version>
...

